# what's functionality of this css snippet?

Tags: css

```
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
```

I don't see any difference whether adding or removing this snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Those are default CSS properties set by the Gecko rendering engine.

## [-moz-background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-clip)

> In Gecko-based applications like Firefox the `-moz-background-clip` CSS property specifies whether an element's background, either the color or image, extends underneath its border
>
> **border**: (initial) The background extends to the outside edge of the border (but underneath the border in z-ordering).
>
> **padding**: No background is drawn below the border (background extends to the outside edge of the padding).

---

## [-moz-background-inline-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-inline-policy)

> In Gecko-based applications like Firefox, the `-moz-background-inline-policy` CSS property specifies how the background image of an inline element is determined when the content of the inline element wraps onto multiple lines. The choice of position has significant effects on repetition.
>
> **bounding-box**: The background image is positioned (and repeated) in the smallest rectangle that contains all of the inline boxes for the element. It is then clipped to be visible only within those boxes, according to the `-moz-background-clip` property.
>
> **continuous**: (Initial) The background image is positioned (and repeated) as if the inline box were not broken across lines, and then this long rectangle is sliced into pieces for each line.
>
> **each-box**: The background image is positioned (and repeated) separately for each box of the inline element. This means that an image with `background-repeat : no-repeat` may be repeated multiple times.

---

## [-moz-background-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-origin)

> In Mozilla applications like Firefox, the `-moz-background-origin` CSS property determines the background positioning area (the origin of a background-image).
>
> **border**: The background position is relative to the border, so the image can go behind the border.
>
> **padding**: (Initial) The background position is relative to the padding.
>
> **content**: The background position is relative to the content.

Answer (score 2):

Tags prefixed with -moz- are nonstandard tags viewable only by Gecko-based browsers, such as Firefox. If you use any other browser, they won't have any effect.

They're usually experimental versions of tags for future standards like CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

[-moz-background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-clip)

[-moz-background-inline-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-inline-policy)

[-moz-background-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-origin)